# Ant target Symlink doesnot work on windows

Tags: java, windows, ant, symlink

I want to create symlink using ant symlink target. I know that symlink internally uses ln -s command supported by linux, Now my major concern is that it should also work on Windows platform, I did search before posting this one. The links out there donot really help when I need to create links on windows using ant symlink target. I donot want to use Cygwin or any other linux simulator for windows to get this working.

*I actually get the below error when i run symlink task on windows*

`setup.links:
  [symlink] ln -s D:\context-rem.xml D:\resources\context-rem.xml`

`Could not launch ln: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ln": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`

Ant command that I use

`<symlink link="context-rem.xml" failOnError="false" resource="resources/context-rem.xml" overwrite="true"/>`

Comment: See: [Straightforward, easy way to create symbolic links on Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/197273/87805).

Answer (score 2):

This Answer to a different Question gives a couple of options for creating the Windows equivalent of a symlink from the command line:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46887/139985

You would need to turn this into an Ant task that runs the relevant Windows command.

Comment: Yeah I did take some alternates not necessarily from the ones mentioned in the link, i used exec ant task and then called mklink command on windows[alternate for symlink], but mklink doesnt run until you open the cmd prompt as an admin[Run as administrator]

Comment: Ant symlink task in ant was originally written (by me) in 2002/2003 time frame. At that time windows support for symlinks was not very good, as a such symlink task was put in the /unix/ package... Another option is to update the symlink task and submit a patch :).

Answer (score 2):

I used next ant task:

```
<exec executable="cmd" os="Windows 10">
    <arg value="/c"/>
    <arg line="mklink /D ${symLinkDir} ${sourceDir}"/>
</exec>
```

where `symLinkDir` is full path to new symlink directory and `sourceDir` is real source dir.